# Windows Server 2012 R2 VPN Block Internet Access

Tags: windows, vpn, internet, restriction

I have set up a VPN connection on Windows Server 2012 R2 using L2TP over IPsec, and using username and password authentication.

The connection works fine however I need to block internet access to the connecting users and just give them access to network resources. Any ideas how this might be accomplished? maybe via a policy or something?

I have searched the internet and it is usually the other way round (giving access to the internet - troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

"WFilter Enterprise" is what you want. You can install it in the server 2012 server to monitor and filter internet access of client deivices.

Comment: Will try it out this week, thanks for the suggestion, will let you know how it went

Answer (score -1):

Google pfsense thats an very good Software Firewall. There you can create also an VPN Tunnel. Be sure to check out the guides from pfsense and it should work.

I know thats not the correct answer for you,  but it is an second way for you, when this gets too complicated for you.

If you need help at the configuration, then open the Website easyserverhelp.de dont worry they are german but they help also english guys

PS: You must install hyper v and create a virtual machine with the pfsense ISO.

Comment: This is a little too off the beaten path. The question just wants a piece of WIndows configuration.